# How to get Assertion Consumer Service URL in AWS IAM Identity center using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-sso, aws-iam-identity-center

How to get Assertion Consumer Service URL in AWS IAM Identity center using AWS CLI?

[image]